# tr '[z-a]' '[a-z]' yields error message

Tags: bash, tr

I want to emulate `rev` command (on alphabet) with the `tr` command

So I did this

```
echo abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz | tr '[z-a]' '[a-z]'
```

That gives me

> tr: range-endpoints of `z-a' are in reverse collating sequence order

So I tried

```
echo abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz | tr 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz' 'zyxvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba'
```

and it works ok, output is `zyxvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba`

That is wrong with `tr '[z-a]' '[a-z]'`?

If I specify `tr '[a-c]' '[c-a]'` it also works fine.

Any help would be appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your lucky with the '[c-a]' thing, My tr says `tr: [c-a]: invalid destination string`, which is what I would expect.

Character ranges, i.e. [a-z], in all the languages I've dealt with, need to ascend in value. 
Be happy that you've already figured out your solution.

Or write a function that you can use like `tr "[a-z]" "[$( revCharRange a-z )]"`
(which would be more expensive due to the sub-shells required to create the reverse character range.

**Edit**
where `revCharRange a-z` would output `zyxw...cba`

I hope this helps.

Comment: I suspect that `[c-a]` is being interpreted as the 5 characters `[`, `c`, ... because `[]` is not required for a character range in `tr` (they were for SysV, but not in POSIX, and modern `tr` tries to allow both with some caveats)

Comment: @BenJackson : Yes, good point, unfortunately my experience goes back to pre-POSIX, and as such infects many of the answers I post ;-) Thanks for the reminder. Good luck to all.

Comment: What can also help is something like this `tr '[a-z A-Z]' '[n-za-m N-ZA-M]'`. You can reverse the order from az to za by putting it in between the character range you want to translate to.  In this case I'm shifting forward by 13 letters (like for Rot13).

Comment: @Gcap: how does that help with reversing order?